# OpenSuse 11.4 set to full screen in VMWare

Tags: display, opensuse

I've been running OpenSuse 11.2 in VMWare and have no problems setting it to full screen. However, after installing OpenSuse 11.4, the resolutions I can choose from doesn't have 1600X900 which is supposed to make it fit in the screen. How can I make 11.4 fit to the screen?

Thanks...

Comment: Install the guest additions.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: *duh* I forgot you're using VMWare, not sure if VMWare has something like VirtualBox's guest additions

Comment: Install VMWare tools instead